# How to locate an element within nested iframes using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, frame

Trying to find the xpath for the `<nobr>` tag at the bottom of the page and it's driving me crazy. The frames are what is complicating the issue. Can someone please tell me the xpath for this?

I am trying to write a selenium script and I have gotten to:

```
EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it, ((By.NAME, "main"))
```

After that none of my xpath attempts have worked to get the content in the `<nobr>` tag where it says supplier.

HTML:

[image: html screenshot]

Comment: `//span[@class="tabSelText"]` ? if there are several entries, add nodes before span

Comment: I understand that part but I'm going wrong with frames somewhere after main. Has anyone any ideas regards that. I've spent way too long trying to figure this out already

Comment: They are nested frames so you'll have to traverse those.  You'll probably have to switch to the frameset first to get the 2nd frame.  Then switch to the frameset inside that frame... then switch to the frame inside that frameset, and that's where your span is.

Comment: Thanks pcalkins. I got a little further down but the next frameset has no id. Will that be possible? frames are new to me when it's this complicated

Comment: This is the next and hopefully final frameset, just not sure how to get into it <frameset rows="48,*" frameborder="NO" border="0">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the delay in coming back with the solution but the problem was that I needed to go up a level from the title iframe to get myself into root and then I was able to go down into main.
A simple problem to have but not so simple when you don't know too much about frames at the time.
I appreciate everyone who took the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option :

```
//nobr[.='Suppliers']/parent::span
```

For the frameset :

```
//frameset[@rows='48,*']
```

Answer (score 0):

As the the desired element is within multiple neted `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *great grand parent* `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *grand parent* `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *parent* `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#main[name='main']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name='marketcenterHome']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#main[name='TabNavigation']")))
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.tabSelText>nobr")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='main' and @name='main']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='marketcenterHome']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='TabNavigation']")))
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='tabSelText']/nobr[text()='Suppliers']")))
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I seem to be having an issue where I cannot switch to main as it cannot be found.
I have successfully switched into the title frame before this on the same level as main and clicked a link.
Is there something I need to do to exit title before I select main?

Comment: Fixed it. I'll post the solution tomorrow